# tornado_json unit testing async methods

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, pytest, pytest-asyncio

I'm trying to set up a unit test for a tornado_json web app.
I'm trying to test a post handler, but I'm failing miserably as the `fetch` method seems to return an _asyncio.Future object, which never seems to complete/have a result set. I've tried to post a summary of the code, at the moment I'm just returning ['test'] item.
I've looked at https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1154, as well as the tornado documentation. It sounds like I need to self.stop, or self.wait() to complete the task, but I haven't worked out how to get this to work, or if that is the solution.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`@schema.validate(
        input_schema={
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "path": {"type": "string"}
            },
            "required": ["path"]
        },
        output_schema={
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "properties": {"type": "string"}
            }
        }
    )
    @coroutine
    def post(self):
        attributes = dict(self.body)
        path = attributes["path"]
        response = ["test"]
        return response`

`@gen_test
    def test_POST_method(self):

        body = json.dumps({'path': 'bin'})
        self.http_client.fetch(self.get_url('/api/listmyfiles'),
            method="POST",
            body=body
        )
        response = self.wait()
        print(response.result()))`

The error I get is:
`asyncio.base_futures.InvalidStateError: Result is not set.`

Answer (score 2):

`AsyncHTTPTestCase` has a few different modes of operation that can't be mixed.

1. `@gen_test`: Used with `await self.http_client.fetch(self.get_url(...))`:

   ```
   @gen_test
   async def test_post_method(self):
       response = await self.http_client.fetch(self.get_url(...))
   ```
2. `self.stop`/`self.wait` is an older interface that is mostly (but not completely) deprecated.  `AsyncHTTPClient` will not be (easily) compatible with this interface in Tornado 6.0, so I won't show an example here.
3. `self.fetch` is a shorthand method that combines the calls to `http_client.fetch` and `self.get_url`, and uses `stop`/`wait` under the covers (so it is not compatible with `@gen_test`):

   ```
   def test_post_method(self):
       response = self.fetch('/api/listmyfiles')
   ```

If the only asynchronous thing you're doing is HTTP fetches, you can use `self.fetch`. If you need to do anything else asynchronous, use `gen_test` and avoid the stop/wait/self.fetch methods.